# Color Guessing game :Uncaught ReferenceError: do_game is not defined at load

Tags: javascript, html, onload

Here is the code in HTML file. I put the `.js` file and `.html` file in the same folder. But I don't know why it's not working. I tried every solution I can find.

### Chrome devtools and console:

[image: html file]

Comment: Try including js file in <head> section.

Comment: Is the first error (file not found) about your js file?

Comment: You want us to debug an image? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Please post your code also.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Color Guessing</title>
</head>
<body onload="do_game()">
<script  type="text/javascript" 
   src="color_guessing_game.js"
   charset="utf-8">
</script>
</body>
</html>